# How to run single class ignoring compilation error in other class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3. I have a project called "test", which has two classes under the src folder:

- `Main`, has main method to print out "Hello World"
- `CompileErrorClass`, has one method with compile errors

[image: project structure picture]

Those two class have no dependencies. I was trying to run the main() in the Main class, and set the before launch to "build, no error check"

[image: run settings picture]

I got an error message

> "Error: Could not find or load main class Main".

When I fixed the compile error in `CompileErrorClass`, the `main()` worked as expected. Or if I ran the same project in Eclipse, it worked fine even with compile error.

How can I setup the run configurations in IntelliJ to run a single class ignoring the compile errors in other class without dependencies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be able to run code with errors you need to make a change in the settings. Go to `Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler` and set the `Use compiler:` combobox to `Eclipse` and enable the `proceed on errors` checkbox. This allows to compile classes even when they have errors.

To start a Run Configuration when the project has errors, you will need `Build, no error check` in the Before Launch section, instead of `Build`.

Comment: It does now try to compile everything but still not run it.

Comment: in the Run configuration it's necessary to change the Before launch settings to "Build, no error check" as shown in the question. Then you should be able to run it.

Comment: @Bas Leijdekkers Only adding "Build, no error check" in the Run configuration of the Main class would suffice to get its output displayed without the compiler change to eclipse or the errors in CompileErrorClass fixed. The full answer, the last answer, is in the following

Comment: April 22, 2021. Is not working for me, perhaps is related to java 11 or last intellij version?

Answer (score 4):

You can put your CompileErrorClass in a folder, then go to "Project Settings/Module" and mark the folder as "Excluded". The folder will be shown on red.

Shorcut: you can "right click" the folder an select "Mark Directory as Excluded".

In the image you can see the "bean" directory in red.[image: Bean directory marked as "Excluded".]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the 'main()' method in the `Main` class and see the output without fixing the errors in the `CompileErrorClass`:

Select the 'Main' class in the project view, go-to Run --> Edit Configurations --> Before Launch and in Before Launch click + and select `Build, no error check` or click '-' take-out(delete) any setting in there  --> Click Ok. If you take-out(using '-') any setting, then 'Before Launch' should not have any setting, its setting should be empty, null.

After the above, right-click on the Main class, and run it. You would see the output. You would see the output even if Use Compiler, which is at Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment -->Compiler --> Java Compile --> Use Compiler, has javac selected as the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are as follows:

1. Set `Do not build before run` (only need to set it once)

   1. Menu → Run → Edit Configurations...
   2. ☑︎ Your run configuration
   3. Run / Modify options → Java / ☑︎ Do not build before run
2. Recompile only selected files (remember to do this step before run)

   1. Select packages or files that needs to be compiled.
   2. Menu → Build → Recompile selected files (<kbd>⇧ ⌘ F9</kbd>)
3. Run or debug your run configuration.